# COM Error 80020005 Type mismatch in Domain User login

Tags: sql-server, windowsdomainaccount

When i run this SQL command in Domain User login, there is

> COM Error 80020005

```
SELECT group_database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'db5'
```

When i run the same command in windows local user, it runs sucessfully.

How does the domain User login differs?

---

Backup failed for Server 'hostname\instancename'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

### To accomplish this action, set property Devices. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows local user is likely the account used to install the instance, making it a sysadmin. The domain user likely doesn't have the permissions to access it.

> If the caller of sys.databases is not the owner of the database and
>   the database is not master or tempdb, the minimum permissions required
>   to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY DATABASE or the VIEW ANY
>   DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE DATABASE permission in the
>   master database. The database to which the caller is connected can
>   always be viewed in sys.databases.
>
> By default, the public role has the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission,
>   allowing all logins to see database information. To block a login from
>   the ability to detect a database, REVOKE the VIEW ANY DATABASE
>   permission from public, or DENY the `VIEW ANY DATABASE permission for
>   individual logins.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Installed the instance with local Administrator. the local user is created as member of Users group, and made as 'sysadmin' server role in SSMS -> Security -> Logins.   Alread the domain user has granted sysadmin server role simllar to the local user. But something is missing.